# Как установить свою dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я добавил в mscorlib.dll свой код - можно ли указать,чтобы vs загружала мою mscorlib для использования,а не стандартную!?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему у вас возникла такая надобность? Почему вы не могли сделать наследование?

Comment: @iluxa1810 какое унаследования?Добавил картинку что поменял

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать.

Каждая сборка подписывается ключем и помещается в GAC.

В метаданных зависимых сборках пишется как раз этот ключ по которому и происходит поиск нужной сборки.

Можно попробовать через App.Config такое провернуть, но опять же, сомневаюсь, что это будет работать, так как данная сборка берется из GAC.